# Does Using PDDocument with try-with-resources guarantee that a file is fully written?

Tags: java, file, pdfbox

If I have the following code:

```
try(PDDocument myDoc = new PDDocument()) {
  // add to myDoc in a giant loop so that the resulting file
  // would be quite large
  .
  .
  .
  myDoc.save("/some/file/path");
}
```

Once I'm outside of the try-with-resources block, am I guaranteed that the file located at `some/file/path` is fully written? I looked into the PDFBox source code but I couldn't get a confirmation.

Comment: You are probably guaranteed that `myDoc` is *closed*

Comment: yes it's fully written after save() finishes and why are you asking this?

Comment: I'm asking this because I have logic after the try-with-resources that handles the file and expects the file to be fully written. I haven't seen evidence that it wouldn't be fully written, but I wanted to get opinions (and potentially) confirmation from others.

Answer (score 2):

If a pdf API contains an explicit `save` method, you can usually assume that it creates a complete pdf file representing the document state at the time you call that method.

If a pdf API early on accepts some `OutputStream` to continously write to, though, it requires some signal when to finalize the output; this signal usually is an explicit `close` call or an implicit closing by `try-with-resources`.

The pdfbox API is of the former type, so the `save` call already suffices. Nonetheless, it's a good idea to explicitly or implicitly close the document here, too, for proper resource handling.

Comment: Let's say that a huge pdf was being written to a network drive somewhere so it takes a few minutes. Does `save()` from the pdfbox API block execution until that file is fully written?

Comment: As far as I know pdfbox essentially in-process writes to a `FileOutputStream` here and eventually closes it.  Thus, it depends on the file system characteristics - if write caching is active, save might finish before all data actually is transferred to the remote site and stored there.